Problem with hosting Angular 18 application in Docker/Kubernetes
I'm currently struggling with a problem I cannot resolve. Already spent hours on lurking for solution..
Stack is Angular + Nginx + Docker + Kubernetes
I need to have two Angular 18 applications on two different paths, let's say /application and /other-application
I want to have following ingress configuration:
 rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /application(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: angular-app-service1
            port:
              number: 80
- host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /other-application(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: angular-app-service2
            port:
              number: 80

At the beginning I realized that Angular 18 application needs adjustments itself so I added following simple changes to angular.json build options:
angular.json -> build -> options:"baseHref": "/application/"
index.html head: <base href="/application/" />

It works locally with ng serve, it automatically redirects to localhost:4200/application - great
I had a problem with Docker which I worked around with custom Nginx configuration looking following:
server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  location /application/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /application/index.html;
  }
  
    location = /application{
        return 301 $scheme://$http_host/application/;
    }

    location = / {
        return 301 $scheme://$http_host/application/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /application/index.html;
    }
}

I replace it with default one in docker file this way - good enough for now:
COPY --from=base app/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

At this point everything works locally with following command:
docker run --rm --name application -it -p 8008:80 container-name
I am able to reach my app under all following addresses which is a main goal for me:

localhost:8008

localhost:8008/application

localhost:8008/application/

localhost:8008/application/login


All of them redirects to localhost:8008/application/login as supposed
Unfortunately, when I deploy it to kubernetes and try to reach: example.com/application or example.com/application/login I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in browser
Maybe it's worth to mention that application works without that custom nginx but routing does not work.
I can reach example.com/application and it redirects correctly to https://example.com/application/login but when I try to reach example.com/application/login directly I get 404 not found.
That's why I'm struggling with that custom configuration for Nginx.
Do you have any idea how can I deal with it? The only additional requirement is that ofc solution has to support parameters in URL.
@Update:
We figured it out and used following nginx config:
server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  location / {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}

This way it works after deployment to kubernetes. However it does not work when you try to run this docker locally so it's not ideal..
